# hHw to make width of bars equal in ggplot2 barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make the width of all bars in the following plot equal. Can anybody help me? is it possible? or is there any way to plot this data?

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = c('I','I','I','I','II','II'),
                  y = LETTERS[1:6],
                  z = abs(rnorm(6)))

ggplot(dat, aes(y,z))+ 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~x,scales="free")
```

I also tried using arguments `size` and `width` inside the `geom_bar` but its not working.
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Really the problem is that each of the facet panels is being forced to be the same size and then the plot inside expands to fill all the available room. With `facet_grid` you can adjust the space for each facet panel (but you cannot seem to do this with `facet_wrap`). Try

```
ggplot(dat, aes(y,z))+ 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(~x,scales="free", space="free_x")
```

which gives me

[image]

Comment: `scales = 'free'`doesnt seem to work. I really want that option

Comment: @MrFlick, I was trying to generate a similar bar plot in Shiny with position = "dodge", however getting all bars 100%. It would be great if you could suggest where I am going wrong. Thank you and sorry for getting in touch in this way. I have posted the question at   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078480/r-shiny-ggplot-bar-and-line-charts-with-dynamic-variable-selection-and-y-axis-to