# R Shiny ggplot bar and line charts with dynamic variable selection and y axis to be percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, data.table, plotly

I am learning Shiny and wanted help on a app that I am creating. I am creating an app that will take dynamic inputs from the user and should generate bar and line charts. I managed to create the bar chart but it is generating incorrect result.

What I am looking for is variable selected in row should be my x-axis and y-axis should be **percentage**. scale to be 100%. column variable should be the variable for comparison and for that I am using `position = "dodge"`. My data is big and I have created a sample data to depict the situation. Since actual data is in data.table format I am storing the sample data as data.table. Since I am not sure how I can include this data which is not in a file format, I create it first so that it is in R environment and then run the app -

```
    Location <- sample(1:5,100,replace = T)
    Brand <- sample(1:3,100,replace = T)
    Year <- rep(c("Year 2014","Year 2015"),50)
    Q1 <- sample(1:5,100,replace = T)
    Q2 <- sample(1:5,100,replace = T)

    mydata <- as.data.table(cbind(Location,Brand,Year,Q1,Q2))
```

Below is the **Shiny** code that I am using -

```
library("shiny")
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
library("data.table")
library("plotly")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(10,
             div(style = "font-size: 13px;", selectInput("rowvar", label = "Select Row Variable", ''))
      ),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      column(10,
             div(style = "font-size: 13px;", selectInput("columnvar", "Select Column Variable", ''))
      ))

  ),
  tabPanel("First Page"),
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(id='charts',
                        tabPanel("charts",tags$b(tags$br("Graphical Output" )),tags$br(),plotlyOutput("plot1"))
  )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  updateTabsetPanel(session = session
                    ,inputId = 'myTabs')


  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "rowvar", choices = (as.character(colnames(mydata))),selected = "mpg")
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "columnvar", choices = (as.character(colnames(mydata))),selected = "cyl")
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    validate(need(input$rowvar,''),
             need(input$columnvar,''))
    ggplot(mydata, aes(x= get(input$rowvar))) + 
      geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = get(input$columnvar)), position = "dodge", stat="count") +
      geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop..),
                     y= ..prop.. ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
      labs(y = "Percent", fill=input$rowvar) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels=percent,limits = c(0,1))

  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you see the problem is -

1. All bars are 100%. Proportions are not getting calculated properly. Not sure where I am going wrong.
2. If I try to use the group parameter it gives me error saying "input" variable not found. I tried giving group as `group = get(input$columnvar)`
3. I believe I need to restructure my data for line chart. Can you help with how I can dynamically restructure the data.table and then re-use for the line chart. How can I generate the same bar chart as a line chart.
4. I am using renderplotly so that I use the features of plotly to have the percentages displayed with the mouse movement / zoom etc. However I can see input$variable on mouse movement. How can I get rid of it and have proper names.

Have tried to detail out the situation. Do suggest some solution.

Thank you!!

Comment: I don't have a complete answer but for 1. maybe in your geom_bar use y = (..count..)/sum(..count..) instead of y = ..prop.. and for 4. in ggplot(mydata, aes(x= get(input$rowvar))) use instead ggplot(mydata, aes_string(x= input$rowvar)); and also replace in geom_text() with geom_text(aes( label = (..count..)/sum(..count..)*100, .......

Comment: @MLavoie, thank you for suggesting, however when I replace the `..prop..` with `(..count..)/sum(..count..)` I start getting error as, object 'count' not found. Not sure if you too get the same error at your end

Comment: no I did not get this error. this is what I used geom_bar(aes(y =  (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill = get(input$columnvar)), position = "dodge", stat="count")

Comment: @MLavoie, It worked, I have been trying multiple things to sort this out and it seems had updated the code as `stat = "identity"` which was giving that error. I changed it back to `stat = "count"` and I am now not getting the error, however the plot generated does not show the correct percentages. I mean addition of all the bars for Year 2014 should be 100% and that of Year 2015 should 100%. Currently not sure how the bar heights are getting calculated. I am checking the bar heights with the table generated by `prop.table(table(mydata$Brand,mydata$Year),2)`. Would you know how to correct this?

Comment: 100% is the sum of all bars

Comment: @MLavoie, Yes I just realized it thank you, however I was looking for a plot where addition of individual years for example would be 100%. So addition of bars for Year 2014 to addup to 100% and addition of bars for year 2015 to add up to 100%. How would we achieve this? Would we need to use group? Sorry I am not sure how we could achieve this. I think we are very close.....

Comment: @MLavoie, Yes I just realized it thank you, however I was looking for a plot where addition of individual years for example would be 100%. So addition of bars for Year 2014 to addup to 100% and addition of bars for year 2015 to add up to 100%. How would we achieve this? Would we need to use group? Sorry I am not sure how we could achieve this. I think we are very close.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130434/discussion-between-prasad-and-mlavoie).

Comment: sorry I have to go will be back later this afternoon

Comment: @MLavoie, thank you!! I look forward to your suggestion later in the day!

Comment: I don't know it's possible what you want. You might have to compute your percentage before plotting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly group variables for plotting, `geom_bar` requires that the `x` values be numeric and the `fill` values be factors or that the argument `group` be used to explicitly specify grouping variables.  However, `plotly` throws an error when `group` is used.  The approach below converts `x` variables to `integer` and `fill` variables to `factor` so that they are properly grouped.  This retains the use of `geom_bar` to calculate the percentages.

First, however,  I wonder if `mydata` is specified correctly.  Given that the data is a mix of character and integer, `cbind(Location, Brand, Year, Q1, Q2)` gives a character matrix which is then converted to a `data.table` where all variables are character mode. In the code below, I've defined mydata directly as a `data.table` but have converted `Q1` to character mode so that `mydata` contains a mix of character and numeric.

The approach used below is to create a new data frame, `plotdata`, containing the `x` and `fill` data.  The `x` data is converted to numeric, if necessary, by first making it a factor variable and then using `unclass` to get the factor integer codes. The `fill` data converted to a factor.  `plotdata` is then used generate the `ggplot` plot which is then displayed using `plotly`.  The code includes a couple of other modifications to improve the appearance of the chart.

**EDIT**

The code below has been updated to show the name of the row variable beneath it's bar.  Also the percentage and count for each bar are only shown when the mouse pointer hovers above the bar.

```
 library("shiny")
  library("ggplot2")
  library("scales")
  library(plotly)
  library(data.table)

  Location <- sample(1:5,100,replace = T)
  Brand <- sample(1:3,100,replace = T)
  Year <- rep(c("Year 2014","Year 2015"),50)
  Q1 <- sample(1:5,100,replace = T)
  Q2 <- sample(1:5,100,replace = T)
  Q3 <- sample(seq(1,3,.5), 100, replace=T)
  mydata <- data.table(Location,Brand,Year,Q1,Q2, Q3)
#
# convert Q1 to character for demonstation purposes  
#
    mydata$Q1 <- as.character(mydata$Q1)

  ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(10,
               div(style = "font-size: 13px;", selectInput("rowvar", label = "Select Row Variable", 
                                                           choices=colnames(mydata)))),
        tags$br(),
        tags$br(),
        column(10,
               div(style = "font-size: 13px;", selectInput("columnvar", label="Select Column Variable", 
                                                           choices=colnames(mydata))))
        )
    ),
    tabPanel("First Page"),
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(id='charts',
                          tabPanel("charts",tags$b(tags$br("Graphical Output" )),tags$br(),plotlyOutput("plot1"))
    )
    )
  ))
  server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
    updateTabsetPanel(session = session
                      ,inputId = 'myTabs')
    observe({
      updateSelectInput(session, "rowvar", choices = colnames(mydata), selected=colnames(mydata)[1])
    })
    observe({
      updateSelectInput(session, "columnvar", choices = colnames(mydata), selected=colnames(mydata)[2])
    })
    output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
#
#   create data frame for plotting containing x variables as integer and fill variables as factors
#   
      if(is.numeric(get(input$rowvar)))  {
        rowvar_brks <- sort(unique(get(input$rowvar)))
        rowvar_lbls <- as.character(rowvar_brks)
        plotdata <- data.frame(get(input$rowvar), factor(get(input$columnvar)) )
      }
      else {
        rowvar_factors <- factor(get(input$rowvar))
        rowvar_brks <- 1:nlevels(rowvar_factors)
        rowvar_lbls <- levels(rowvar_factors)
        plotdata <- data.frame(unclass(rowvar_factors), factor(get(input$columnvar)) )
      }
      colnames(plotdata) <- c(input$rowvar, input$columnvar)
      validate(need(input$rowvar,''),
               need(input$columnvar,''))
      col_width <- .85*mean(diff(rowvar_brks))
      sp <- ggplot(plotdata, aes_(x = as.name(input$rowvar), fill = as.name(input$columnvar))) +
        geom_bar( aes(y= ..prop..), stat="count", position=position_dodge(width=col_width)) +
        geom_text(aes( label = paste(scales::percent(..prop..),"<br>", "count:",..count..,"<br>"),  y= ..prop.. + .01),
                  stat= "count", position=position_dodge(width=col_width), size=3, alpha=0) +
        labs(x= input$rowvar, y = "Percent", fill=input$columnvar) +
        scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks=rowvar_brks, labels=rowvar_lbls)
        ggplotly(sp, tooltip="none")
      })
  })

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation. It really helps. I managed to replicate the code. However as mentioned above data was sample and my actual data has quite a few variables and most of them I have converted to factors to keep the labels, so that when I plot the chart I have the labels displayed automatically in Shiny. This code solves the problem of percentage calculation, but I loose the labels. How can I keep the labels for all factor variables in x-axis.

Comment: Also incase a variable has many codes the percentages become cluttered and spoil the look of the chart. I can not paste image in comment and hope you get what I mean. example I have a variable with 20 codes in x-axis and chart gets cluttered with percentages. Can we update the tooltip to display count + percentage and remove the percentage from top of the bars? Thank you once again Walts and hope you would help me out for these points.

Comment: @WaltS, In this case I believe one would need to restructure the data for line charts? Could you please help with some example on how it can be done. Also having tool tips with count and percentage boths seems to be very interesting to have...

Comment: @Prasad.  I think the edited code addresses the items in your comments.

Comment: @Walts, Thank you very much!! this is working in the environment of the sample code however when I try to replicate this in my actual app, getting error object "(variable name)" not found....I feel it is not able to refer to the variables in the data.....not sure where I am going wrong. Only difference is that in my actual app I am asking user to provide csv data and then I am re-formatting the data in observeEvent({..data reformating..rendertable..renderplot..}) with the actionbutton....all my table output and plots are inside this observeEvent.....Is it not the right way to do scoping?

Comment: @Prasad,  It's hard to say without seeing the actual code.  If you feel that the answer I've given above answers the original question, perhaps you could Accept this answer and post the issue about reading the file in a new question.

Comment: @WaltS, Yes, I have accepted your answer though it would have been great to have some suggestion on point 3 related to line charts. I have still not managed to replicate this code in my original code & as you suggested, I have posted another question related to filter of dataset for generating tables & plots, & have kept the code snippet inline with my original code. It would help a lot if you could have alook at the code & suggest. Link to question is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187194/shiny-dynamic-filter-variable-selection-and-display-of-variable-values-for-sel   Thank you WaltS!!